# Multiple App Export to Application Insights from App center

Tags: devops, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

I have configured continuous export of my mobile App from App center to Application Insights.
All my logs and crash reports are moving from App center to Application Insights.

Problem is am not able to uniquely identify the Application in Application Insights.

Comment: what do you mean that not able to uniquely identify the application? does it mean that apply filter to show only your application's log? if possible, you'd better provide more details like screenshots, detailed steps etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that filter out only the logs of your application in app insights, then there are a lot of properties you can use in the search page, which can help identify your application. If I'm misunderstood, please correct me.
[image]